# Java parsing a string of floats to a float array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, floating-point

Is there a simple way to parse a string of floats to a float array? I'm writing an importer which needs to parse an ascii file to get some values out and I'm just wondering if there's a simpler way to do this then search for all the whitespace myself and use `Float.parseFloat(s)` for each whitespace-separated value.

For example, the string is

`1 0 4 0 26 110.78649609798859 39 249.34908705094128 47 303.06802752888359`

I want to create an array of floats as:

`[1, 0, 4, 0, 26, 110.78649609798859, 39, 249.34908705094128, 47, 303.06802752888359]`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a Scanner [[API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)]

Use the `Scanner#hasNextFloat` and `Scanner#nextFloat` methods to loop through and get all of the floats and build them into an array.

Comment: Jasons's solution is actually much more efficient, Scanner is significantly slower.

Answer (score 8):

You can do like this

Split the String

> String[] split(String regex) 
>             Splits this string around matches of the given regular
>   expression.

```
String[] tabOfFloatString = bigStringWithAllFloats.split(regex);
```

regex can be space, tab, comma whatever (advantage of regex is you can combine all you want, I use this in my xml reader "[-+.,:;]" ); 
then loop on that and convert to floats

```
for(String s : tabOfFloatString){
    float res = Float.parseFloat(s);
    //do whatever you want with the float
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`java.util.Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want an array of float, the easy way is to split the string:

```
String[] flostr = myString.split(" ");
float[] floats = new float[flostr.length];
```

and then iterate on the string array, and parse the single float values.

Alternatively, you could use a Scanner or a StringTokenizer, put all values into a List and create an array at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) solution, but I'm surprised at how complicated it apparently needs to be. Perhaps someone can give me a hint as how to shorten it:

```
public static float[] extractFloats(final String input){
    // check for null Strings
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(input);
    return Floats.toArray(Lists.transform(
        Lists.newArrayList(Splitter.on(Pattern.compile("\\s+")).split(
            input.trim())), new Function<String, Float>(){

            @Override
            public Float apply(final String input){
                return Float.valueOf(input);
            }
        }));
}
```

**Test Code:**

```
String param =
    "1 0 4 0 26 110.78649609798859 39 249.34908705094128 47 303.06802752888359";
float[] floats = extractFloats(param);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(floats));
```

**Output:**

> [1.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 26.0, 110.7865, 39.0, 249.34909, 47.0, 303.06802]