# How to get multiple variables from one EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm looking for a way to get three float values from one EditText.I've Looked of the developers page but i couldnt find anything that best fit my need.I would like to get three floats a x,y,z from one entry of EditText?

Thank you guys so much on the replys o this Question im really greatfull.
Im limited to the time on my computer right now but ill let you know which answer work for me and ill post my code too.

Comment: Why not three `EditText` widgets? How are you planning on the user indicating the three different values in one `EditText`?

Comment: I will have a TextView asking for x,y,z. I was just wondering if there was a way to do this on one line instead of having three EditTexts. For my design I think it will be just a pain. In the future i will want to add other commands so i am limited on screen space.

Comment: What you want is not important. What the *user* wants is what's important. Expecting users to adhere to some particular syntax for denoting three floating-point values is annoying to the user, particularly on small soft keyboards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String value = yourEditText.getText().toString();
String[] floatStrings = value.split(",");
float[] result = new float[floatString.length];
for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = Float.valueOf(floatStrings[i];
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If they are separated by whitespaces

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(yourEditText.getText().toString());

float vals = new float[3];

while(int i=0; sc.hasNextFloat() && (i < 3); ++i) {
   vals[i] = sc.nextFloat();
}
```

otherwise use `Scanner.setDelimiter` to set delimiter(s) other than whitespaces.

Reconsider your design to use three EditTexts instead. On mobile phones it's a pain to enter symbols like comma

Answer (score 0):

Use 3 EditText widgets if you want the user to input 3 separate values, which will be parsed as 3 separate variables.

Answer (score -1):

You should either create several EditText views, or then parse the contents of the EditText

```
EditText textView;

String[] splitFloatStrings = textView.getText().toString();.split(",");
float[] parsedFloats = new float[splitFloatStrings.length];

for (int i=0; i < parsedFloats.length; i++) {
    parsedFloats[i] = Float.valueOf(splitFloatStrings[i];
}
```

As per [Java parsing a string of floats to a float array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202712/java-parsing-a-string-of-floats-to-a-float-array)

Comment: You forgot to paste "and then iterate on the string array, and parse the single float values" from that answer you are referring to.

Comment: @Alex added the iteration.