# Retrieving multiple variables from one EditText

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have been working on creating a Translator app. I got no trouble retrieving one data from a database. I would like to get multiple strings from one entry of EditText and show it in one TextView. Here is my code:

```
db = new DatabaseHelper(super.getActivity()).getWritableDatabase();

searchText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchText);
melanauTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

Button btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View V) {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM translate WHERE malayText = ?", 
                             new String[]{searchText.getText().toString()});

        if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.moveToFirst()))
                    melanauTextView.setText(String.format("%s", 
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("melanauText"))));

    }
}
```

Any advice or points would be very appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use 'searchView' instead of 'EditText' .see this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

Comment: You have to cycle through results by using `cursor.moveToNext()` until there are rows. But `you will need a ListView` (or a similar `ViewGroup`), to list the `multiple results`, won't you?

Comment: @DerGolem can I use this code to modify the existing code? [links](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17032693/4972383)

Comment: No. You need a loop to cycle through the returned rows to fill an adapter (or use a CursorAdapter), Which will be assigned to a ListView.